# open source piano keyboard ios

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios-4.2

Is there any open source code for creating a piano keyboard with sounds for ios?  I have looked but have not found one, or offer a good recommendation were to start, AVAudioPlayer. or systemSoundID

Comment: you should post that as an answer!  While not exactly what the person wants as a fully developed solution, it does put him on the path of getting his own stuff up and running.

Comment: Ok I did as you suggested and added as an answer, it wouldn't let me do so earlier so I posted the comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this great tutorial, it is a little advanced but perfect for learning.  I already have a simple version up and running using this tutorial

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_playing-systemsoundid/

Answer (score 7):

Here is one you can try. It is something I started a while back and have not had time to finish because of my day job.

https://github.com/yepher/MusicNotes

Comment: For what it's worth, I was able to download files from Github, open MusicNotes.xcodeproj from Xcode 5.0.1, build to my iPhone 5S and begin using the app. Well done and thank you for open-sourcing. Love the slider overlay on the full piano keyboard. 2013-11-16

Comment: @Yepher: We want to use the structure provided by you into one of your apps. How do we get permission from you? We will put a reference in header files to your repository. Will that be enough?

Comment: You can use it the way you want. Treat it as BSD license. I would appreciate knowing where it is used and pull requests for anything that you feel improves the project (but that is not required). If you have other license requirements shoot me an email. You can find my address in GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried a few solutions, and eventually used this [piano keyboard for iOS](http://www.binpress.com/app/piano-keyboard-for-ios/1282), since I couldn't get rid of the lag which is crucial when using it as part of a multitracker for timing issues (an app I'm working on).

I learned a lot from going over the code and through the support I got from the author, so even though it wasn't free I was very pleased with it.